# How to implement retry not on the superclass exception like on RuntimeException But my code throws RestClientException?

Tags: spring, spring-retry

Here is my code for retry:

```
@Retryable(value = RestClientException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    public <T, S> ResponseEntity<T> sendPostRequest(String url,
                                                    S requestObject,
                                                    Class<T> responseClazz,
                                                    HttpHeaders headers) {
        ResponseEntity<T> response = null;
        try {
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<S> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestObject, headers);
            response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, responseClazz);
            return response;
        } catch(HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
            response = new ResponseEntity(ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), ex.getStatusCode());
        } catch(RestClientException rce) {
            log.error("Error occurred.: {}", rce.getMessage());
            throw new ServerErrorException("Exception throw");
        }
        return response;
    }
```

log in console:

```
Error occurred.: I/O error on POST request for "https://thirdpartyapi.com": Read timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

According to my code it needs to retry for 3 times and after that it will throw error. But it is throwing on the first attempt.

When I change the retryable annotation to this:

```
@Retryable(value = RuntimeException.class, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
```

Now my code works in the correct logic.
RuntimeException is the super class of the RestClientException and spring-retry is working for the superclass exceptions only.
But I want a more control on my code and implement the retry logic for the fewer Exceptions. RuntimeException is extended to various others exception.

How to implement the retry logic to the non super class exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't throw `RestClientException`, it throws `ServerErrorException` (you're catching it and throwing a new one).

So when you're using `RuntimeException` it does work, as `ServerErrorException` fits. either change your catch clause to throw the original exception or use `ServerErrorException` on the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can set any exception in the "value" attribute, not only the base one.
Also, you can specify [more than one exception](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/retry/annotation/Retryable.java#L59):

```
@Retryable(value = {FirstException.class, SecondException.class}, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
```